# calculate product variants based on option groups and options in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, e-commerce

I have a json response that I will add it below and it contains some variants for a product in an ecommerce app that's written with Flutter, I'm already sorting the variants based on the types (So a product may have one type of variant and a product may have two types of variants). the only thing now I'm stuck at is I want to show only that variants in the second type that's only available in one of the variants in the first one (So the second type variants is changing based on the variants selected in the first types of variants).
The json contains a lot of informations that I think make it possible to make algorithms in different ways.
So basically to make it more clear I want second row of variants to be changed based on the selection of the first row of variants:
[image]

The json response is below:

```
{
    "data": {
        "attributes": [
            {
                "id": 28,
                "code": "weightgram",
                "label": "weight",
                "swatch_type": "text",
                "options": [
                    {
                        "id": 66,
                        "label": "40 grams",
                        "swatch_value": null,
                        "products": [
                            118,
                            120,
                            121,
                            122,
                            126
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 67,
                        "label": " 145 grams",
                        "swatch_value": null,
                        "products": [
                            127,
                            128,
                            130
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 33,
                "code": "taste",
                "label": "taste",
                "swatch_type": "text",
                "options": [
                    {
                        "id": 58,
                        "label": "cocoa",
                        "swatch_value": null,
                        "products": [
                            118
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 59,
                        "label": " dark chocolate",
                        "swatch_value": null,
                        "products": [
                            120,
                            127
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 60,
                        "label": "watermelon",
                        "swatch_value": null,
                        "products": [
                            121,
                            128
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 61,
                        "label": "milk",
                        "swatch_value": null,
                        "products": [
                            122
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 62,
                        "label": "apple",
                        "swatch_value": null,
                        "products": [
                            130
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 65,
                        "label": "cherry",
                        "swatch_value": null,
                        "products": [
                            126
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "index": {
            "118": {
                "28": 66,
                "33": 58
            },
            "120": {
                "28": 66,
                "33": 59
            },
            "121": {
                "28": 66,
                "33": 60
            },
            "122": {
                "28": 66,
                "33": 61
            },
            "126": {
                "28": 66,
                "33": 65
            },
            "127": {
                "28": 67,
                "33": 59
            },
            "128": {
                "28": 67,
                "33": 60
            },
            "130": {
                "28": 67,
                "33": 62
            }
        },
        "regular_price": {
            "formated_price": "0 IQD",
            "price": "0.0000"
        },
        "variant_prices": {
            "118": {
                "regular_price": {
                    "price": 249.69000000000003,
                    "formated_price": "250 IQD"
                },
                "final_price": {
                    "price": 249.69000000000003,
                    "formated_price": "250 IQD"
                }
            },
            "120": {
                "regular_price": {
                    "price": 249.69000000000003,
                    "formated_price": "250 IQD"
                },
                "final_price": {
                    "price": 249.69000000000003,
                    "formated_price": "250 IQD"
                }
            },
            "121": {
                "regular_price": {
                    "price": 249.69000000000003,
                    "formated_price": "250 IQD"
                },
                "final_price": {
                    "price": 249.69000000000003,
                    "formated_price": "250 IQD"
                }
            },
            "122": {
                "regular_price": {
                    "price": 249.69000000000003,
                    "formated_price": "250 IQD"
                },
                "final_price": {
                    "price": 249.69000000000003,
                    "formated_price": "250 IQD"
                }
            },
            "126": {
                "regular_price": {
                    "price": 249.69000000000003,
                    "formated_price": "250 IQD"
                },
                "final_price": {
                    "price": 249.69000000000003,
                    "formated_price": "250 IQD"
                }
            },
            "127": {
                "regular_price": {
                    "price": 999.9899999999999,
                    "formated_price": "1.000 IQD"
                },
                "final_price": {
                    "price": 999.9899999999999,
                    "formated_price": "1.000 IQD"
                }
            },
            "128": {
                "regular_price": {
                    "price": 999.9899999999999,
                    "formated_price": "1.000 IQD"
                },
                "final_price": {
                    "price": 999.9899999999999,
                    "formated_price": "1.000 IQD"
                }
            },
            "130": {
                "regular_price": {
                    "price": 999.9899999999999,
                    "formated_price": "1.000 IQD"
                },
                "final_price": {
                    "price": 999.9899999999999,
                    "formated_price": "1.000 IQD"
                }
            }
        },
        "variant_images": {
            "118": [
                {
                    "small_image_url": "/cache/small/product/118/SPfrV2l5kz48vrKQovk34cY8S02akdnEnl73hgbw.png",
                    "medium_image_url": "/cache/medium/product/118/SPfrV2l5kz48vrKQovk34cY8S02akdnEnl73hgbw.png",
                    "large_image_url": "/cache/large/product/118/SPfrV2l5kz48vrKQovk34cY8S02akdnEnl73hgbw.png",
                    "original_image_url": "/cache/original/product/118/SPfrV2l5kz48vrKQovk34cY8S02akdnEnl73hgbw.png"
                }
            ],
            "120": [
                {
                    "small_image_url": "/cache/small/product/120/3VuqajunccnCz9Qjyqv4JY3RF321b750l75toWnh.jpeg",
                    "medium_image_url": "/cache/medium/product/120/3VuqajunccnCz9Qjyqv4JY3RF321b750l75toWnh.jpeg",
                    "large_image_url": "/cache/large/product/120/3VuqajunccnCz9Qjyqv4JY3RF321b750l75toWnh.jpeg",
                    "original_image_url": "/cache/original/product/120/3VuqajunccnCz9Qjyqv4JY3RF321b750l75toWnh.jpeg"
                }
            ],
            "121": [
                {
                    "small_image_url": "/cache/small/product/121/9Pu1GLDqewlPr2akSw2vwNOvd6rnpWLY6Q4OTlyu.png",
                    "medium_image_url": "/cache/medium/product/121/9Pu1GLDqewlPr2akSw2vwNOvd6rnpWLY6Q4OTlyu.png",
                    "large_image_url": "/cache/large/product/121/9Pu1GLDqewlPr2akSw2vwNOvd6rnpWLY6Q4OTlyu.png",
                    "original_image_url": "/cache/original/product/121/9Pu1GLDqewlPr2akSw2vwNOvd6rnpWLY6Q4OTlyu.png"
                }
            ],
            "122": [
                {
                    "small_image_url": "/cache/small/product/122/QLflc1kYQrJK9SyuH0UmTOYd6BfDQIBE3QKebEIU.png",
                    "medium_image_url": "/cache/medium/product/122/QLflc1kYQrJK9SyuH0UmTOYd6BfDQIBE3QKebEIU.png",
                    "large_image_url": "/cache/large/product/122/QLflc1kYQrJK9SyuH0UmTOYd6BfDQIBE3QKebEIU.png",
                    "original_image_url": "/cache/original/product/122/QLflc1kYQrJK9SyuH0UmTOYd6BfDQIBE3QKebEIU.png"
                }
            ],
            "126": [
                {
                    "small_image_url": "/cache/small/product/126/ftviQbYvbgxamI6VdhdhqwSMdNI7qd9238MQds72.png",
                    "medium_image_url": "/cache/medium/product/126/ftviQbYvbgxamI6VdhdhqwSMdNI7qd9238MQds72.png",
                    "large_image_url": "/cache/large/product/126/ftviQbYvbgxamI6VdhdhqwSMdNI7qd9238MQds72.png",
                    "original_image_url": "/cache/original/product/126/ftviQbYvbgxamI6VdhdhqwSMdNI7qd9238MQds72.png"
                }
            ],
            "127": [
                {
                    "small_image_url": "/cache/small/product/127/TEixBE3h5wABfYT1RKVNo6aT1Hc68lyI0UHhD5yu.jpeg",
                    "medium_image_url": "/cache/medium/product/127/TEixBE3h5wABfYT1RKVNo6aT1Hc68lyI0UHhD5yu.jpeg",
                    "large_image_url": "/cache/large/product/127/TEixBE3h5wABfYT1RKVNo6aT1Hc68lyI0UHhD5yu.jpeg",
                    "original_image_url": "/cache/original/product/127/TEixBE3h5wABfYT1RKVNo6aT1Hc68lyI0UHhD5yu.jpeg"
                }
            ],
            "128": [
                {
                    "small_image_url": "/cache/small/product/128/IHPow4CP4J8u9pAlERbVTh1OeYqfHeiewth1nrmA.png",
                    "medium_image_url": "/cache/medium/product/128/IHPow4CP4J8u9pAlERbVTh1OeYqfHeiewth1nrmA.png",
                    "large_image_url": "/cache/large/product/128/IHPow4CP4J8u9pAlERbVTh1OeYqfHeiewth1nrmA.png",
                    "original_image_url": "/cache/original/product/128/IHPow4CP4J8u9pAlERbVTh1OeYqfHeiewth1nrmA.png"
                }
            ],
            "130": [
                {
                    "small_image_url": "/cache/small/product/130/Wm8VNAlVZfMtKBfjtckvYDUVCCvZ65kV5t7INLqa.jpeg",
                    "medium_image_url": "/cache/medium/product/130/Wm8VNAlVZfMtKBfjtckvYDUVCCvZ65kV5t7INLqa.jpeg",
                    "large_image_url": "/cache/large/product/130/Wm8VNAlVZfMtKBfjtckvYDUVCCvZ65kV5t7INLqa.jpeg",
                    "original_image_url": "/cache/original/product/130/Wm8VNAlVZfMtKBfjtckvYDUVCCvZ65kV5t7INLqa.jpeg"
                }
            ]
        },
        "chooseText": "choose one"
    }
}
```

And the flutter code is below:

```
StreamBuilder(
                          stream: varientBloc.allVarients,
                          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Varient> snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.hasData) {
                              price =
                                  snapshot.data.data.regularPrice.formatedPrice;

                              return Column(
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        right: 8, left: 8),
                                    child: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                          snapshot.data.data.attributes[0]
                                                  .options.length
                                                  .toString() +
                                              ' ' +
                                              snapshot.data.data.attributes[0]
                                                  .label,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                        Icon(Icons.arrow_right)
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  ToggleButtonGenerator(
                                    snapshot: snapshot.data.data.attributes[0],
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: Divider(color: Colors.grey[300]),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        right: 8, left: 8),
                                    child: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                          snapshot.data.data.attributes[1]
                                                  .options.length
                                                  .toString() +
                                              ' ' +
                                              snapshot.data.data.attributes[1]
                                                  .label,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                        Icon(Icons.arrow_right)
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  ToggleButtonGenerator(
                                    snapshot: snapshot.data.data.attributes[1],
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: Divider(color: Colors.grey[300]),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              );
                            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                              return Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                    0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0),
                                child: SliverToBoxAdapter(
                                  child: Text(
                                      'AppLocalizations.of(context).sorry_something_wrong_happened'),
                                ),
                              );
                            }
                            return Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0),
                              child: Container(
                                child: Center(
                                    child: Shimmer.fromColors(
                                        baseColor: Colors.grey[300],
                                        highlightColor: Colors.grey[100],
                                        child: Column(
                                          children: [Text('data')],
                                        ))),
                              ),
                            );
                          }),

import 'package:models/varient.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ToggleButtonGenerator extends StatefulWidget {
  final Attribute snapshot;

  const ToggleButtonGenerator({
    Key key,
    @required this.snapshot,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ToggleButtonGeneratorState createState() => _ToggleButtonGeneratorState();
}

class _ToggleButtonGeneratorState extends State<ToggleButtonGenerator> {
  List<bool> isFirstSelected;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    isFirstSelected =
        List.generate(widget.snapshot.options.length, (_) => false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: ToggleButtons(
        borderColor: Colors.transparent,
        fillColor: Colors.transparent,
        selectedBorderColor: Colors.transparent,
        children: List.generate(widget.snapshot.options.length, (index) {
          return Card(
            elevation: 3,
            color:
                isFirstSelected[index] == true ? Colors.red : Colors.red[200],
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0)),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(14.0, 10.0, 14.0, 10.0),
              child: Text(
                widget.snapshot.options[index].label,
                style:
                    TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }),

        // logic for button selection below
        onPressed: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            for (int i = 0; i < isFirstSelected.length; i++) {
              isFirstSelected[i] = i == index;
            }

            print('the Selected ID');
            print(widget.snapshot.options[index].id);
          });
        },
        isSelected: isFirstSelected,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a year I don't quietly remember, If I'm not wrong I solved it but there was a little bug, I will add the code below. please test it because I didn't work on this project after solving this.

```
StreamBuilder(
                                  stream: variantBloc.allVarients,
                                  builder: (context,
                                      AsyncSnapshot<Variant.Variant>
                                          snapshot) {
                                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                      return Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                            bottom: 8.0),
                                        child: Column(
                                          children: [
                                            Padding(
                                              padding:
                                                  const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                      right: 8, left: 8),
                                              child: Row(
                                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                                    MainAxisAlignment
                                                        .spaceBetween,
                                                children: [
                                                  Text(
                                                    snapshot
                                                            .data
                                                            .data
                                                            .attributes[0]
                                                            .options
                                                            .length
                                                            .toString() +
                                                        ' ' +
                                                        snapshot
                                                            .data
                                                            .data
                                                            .attributes[0]
                                                            .label,
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                        fontWeight:
                                                            FontWeight
                                                                .bold),
                                                  ),
                                                  Icon(Icons.arrow_right)
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            ToggleButtonGenerator(
                                              snapshot: snapshot.data.data,
                                              row: 0,
                                              attributesIndex:
                                                  snapshot.data.data.index,
                                              variantPrice: snapshot
                                                  .data.data.variantPrices,
                                              variantImage: snapshot
                                                  .data.data.variantImages,
                                            ),
                                            snapshot.data.data.attributes
                                                        .length >
                                                    1
                                                ? Consumer<
                                                        SecondRowProvider>(
                                                    builder: (context,
                                                        variant, child) {
                                                    return SecondToggleButtonGenerator(
                                                      key: GlobalKey(),
                                                      rowName: snapshot
                                                          .data
                                                          .data
                                                          .attributes[1],
                                                      snapshot: variant
                                                          .secondRowOptions,
                                                      attributesIndex:
                                                          snapshot.data.data
                                                              .index,
                                                      variantPrice: snapshot
                                                          .data
                                                          .data
                                                          .variantPrices,
                                                      variantImage: snapshot
                                                          .data
                                                          .data
                                                          .variantImages,
                                                    );
                                                  })
                                                : Container(),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                      return Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                            0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0),
                                        child: Center(
                                          child: Text(
                                              snapshot.error.toString()),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    }
                                    return Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                          0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0),
                                      child: Container(
                                        child: Center(
                                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                                valueColor:
                                                    AlwaysStoppedAnimation(
                                                        Color(
                                                            0xFFFF0000)))),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  })
```

Comment: @iamnabink, Please test it, hope it helps.